# Error while running Tensorflow on SQL Server (ImportError: DLL load failed: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.)

Tags: python, sql, tensorflow

I am faced with this error while running Tensorflow on SQL Server.

It seems like it is some memory issue. 
Any advice?

Main Error: ImportError: DLL load failed: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.

```
Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 1
A 'Python' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
An external script error occurred: 

Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:34: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
An external script error occurred: 
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete
```